# Neo4j PHP Graphaware '415 Unsupported Media Type '

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

The following test case (assuming correct password)

```
    <?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
    use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;
    
        $client = ClientBuilder::create()
        ->addConnection('default','http://neo4j:neo4j@localhost:7474')
        ->build();
    
        $result = $client->run('match (n:person) return n');
```

gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Http\Client\Common\Exception\ClientErrorException: Unsupported Media Type in C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Xamp\htdocs\Neo4j\vendor\php-http\client-common\src\Plugin\ErrorPlugin.php:72 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Xamp\htdocs\Neo4j\vendor\php-http\client-common\src\Plugin\ErrorPlugin.php(54):HttpClientCommonPluginErrorPlugin->transformResponseToException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1 C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Xamp\htdocs\Neo4j\vendor\php-http\httplug\src\Promise\HttpFulfilledPromise.php(34): Http\Client\Common\Plugin\ErrorPlugin->Http\Client\Common\Plugin\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2 C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Xamp\htdocs\Neo4j\vendor\php-http\client-common\src\Plugin\ErrorPlugin.php(55): Http\Client\Promise\HttpFulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure)) #3 C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Xamp\htdocs\Neo4j\vendor\php-http\client-common\src\PluginClient.php(161): Http\Client\Common\Plugin\ErrorPlugin->handleRequest(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(Closure), in C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\Xamp\htdocs\Neo4j\vendor\php-http\client-common\src\Plugin\ErrorPlugin.php on line 72
```

This is the $client when I var_dump it:

```
object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Client)#7 (2) {
  ["connectionManager":protected]=>
  object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\ConnectionManager)#2 (2) {
    ["connections":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\ConnectionManager":private]=>
    array(1) {
      ["default"]=>
      object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection)#4 (5) {
        ["alias":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=>
        string(7) "default"
        ["uri":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=>
        string(38) "http://neo4j:Password@localhost:7474"
        ["driver":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=>
        object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Driver)#6 (2) {
          ["uri":protected]=>
          string(38) "http://neo4j:Password@localhost:7474"
          ["config":protected]=>
          object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Configuration)#5 (1) {
            ["timeout":protected]=>
            int(5)
          }
        }
        ["session":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=>
        NULL
        ["timeout":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=>
        int(5)
      }
    }
    ["master":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\ConnectionManager":private]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["eventDispatcher":protected]=>
  object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)#8 (2) {
    ["listeners":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["sorted":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to interpret this or what is wrong.

- My database is running properly in the neo4j browser client.
- As far as I know graphaware is installed appropriately, as per the
  instructions on the website.
- I have tested and the error occurs at the point of running the query,
  not at the point of creating the client (even though this is    not
  indicated clearly by the error)
- If I copy / paste the query directly into the neo4j browser client
  then it works as expected.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

I see the same problem :(

I debugged it into HttpDriver/Session.php flush function and I think headers are set up incorrectly:

```
public function flush(Pipeline $pipeline)
    {
        $request = $this->prepareRequest($pipeline);
        try {
            $response = $this->httpClient->sendRequest($request);

value of request
[headers:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request:private] => Array
        (
            [Host] => Array
                (
                    [0] => localhost:7474
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [X-Stream] => 1
                    [Content-Type] => application/json
                )

        )
```

Pretty sure the request should be like this:

```
Array
        (
            [Host] => Array
                (
                    [0] => localhost:7474
                )
            [X-Stream] => 1
            [Content-Type] => application/json
        )
```

To fix this I modified PrepareRequst function to generate correct headers

```
// Line 197
$headers = [
  'X-Stream' => true,
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
];
```